# Does AWS request signing hide the access key?

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I [sign a request to the AWS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) and I then forward this request to a client to have it execute the request, can the client (given the request) reverse engineer the access key that was used?

In other words, if I sign a request with my access key, can I safely have someone else execute that request for me, without them knowing the access key?

And can the client see the request contents that are being fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your access key id will be visible but your secret access key will not. Signing a request does not encrypt the contents so the contents would still be readable.

Comment: Thank you. And is exposing the access key ID considered insecure and bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

The `access key` technically  is **not a secret**.

For example, it is stored as a **plain text** in any [pre-sign s3 url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) that you give out to people or post on your website:

```
https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA4CHRFYIMJSLJKLHO&Signature=cD47pThlUZ%2BUmfkA0DLAEf%2BxiyU%3D&Expires=1591143311
```

What's more, you `access key` is always in plain text when you do requests to AWS. The request has the [form](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html) shown below, where `access key ID` is in plain text:

```
Authorization: algorithm Credential=access key ID/credential scope, SignedHeaders=SignedHeaders, Signature=signature
```

Think about `access key` and `secret access key` as `username` and `password`. `Username` can be publicly know, but `password` not. Thus if someone gets an `access key` from the signed url there is no major issue, because its not secret as AWS openly stores it in **plain text** in the urls.

Having said that, its still recommended not to give it away for no reason. Thus instead of using your access key in plain text from your admin account in your pre-sign S3 urls or signed requests, you can create a temporary IAM user with just enough credentials to perform the actions needed. This is line with **a good practice** of [Grant Least Privilege](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege).